Which file specify Oracle's DB full version (major and minor)? Oracle 19 and up
In some monitoring service I have, I need to detect Oracle DB upgrades/patches, and for that, I want to sample the Database version.
I am aware that creating a connection and running the query select * from v$version; will provide this information, output example :
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.21.0.0.0


but I only have access to the file system.
In configuration files such as /etc/oratab only the Release version is documented (in this case - 19.0.0.0.0) and not the full version which also contains information about patches that were applied (in this case -19.21.0.0.0).
Where does the connection extract this information from?
Side note - On other Oracle utilities, such as OPatch there is a file containing the version :
$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/version.txt holds this string: OPATCH_VERSION:12.2.0.1.43
Is there a similar file for the full Oracle DB version?

Best to use SQL for this as you've already mentioned.
To my knowledge, there is no file that is maintained that shows the database software version as well as the release updates applied. A workaround may be to have a shell script save the output of opatch lspatches or opatch lsinventory and programmatically parse the output to retrieve the database version. You could also spool out your own version.txt file by periodically running SQL*Plus and selecting from V$VERSION, then have your monitoring service reference this file.
